# Filter output received from subprocess.check_call

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, subprocess, popen

What specific syntax needs to be added to the Python 3 script below in order for the script to filter through each line of the results and evaluate whether any of the lines of output contain specific substrings?

Here is the code which now successfully runs a `git clone` command:

```
newpath="C:\\path\\to\\destination\\"
cloneCommand='git clone https://github.com/someuser/somerepo.git'
proc = subprocess.check_call(cloneCommand, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, cwd=newpath, timeout=None)
```

The above successfully clones the intended repo.  But the problem is that there is not error handling.

I would like to be able to have the script listen for the words `deltas` and `done` in each line of output so that it can indicate success when the following line is printed in the output:

```
Resolving deltas: 100% (164/164), done.
```

`subprocess.Popen(...)` allows us to filter each line of the streaming output.  However, `subprocess.Popen(...)` does not work when we run remote commands like `git clone` because `subprocess.Popen(...)` does not wait to receive the return from a remote call like `git clone`.

What syntax do we need to use to filter the output from calls to `subprocess.check_call(...)`?

Comment: If you want to run the command to completion and then process its output, you can use `subprocess.check_output()`. If you need more information and control (eg, exit code and separation between STDOUT and STDERR), create a `Popen()` instance and then use its `communicate()` method to get the outputs.

Comment: @FMc  Can you please demonstrate how, including code.

Answer (score 0):

A small script that we can execute to test our `Popen` code. It generates some STDOUT and STDERR before exiting with a code of our choosing, optionally with some delay:

```
from sys import stdout, stderr, exit, argv
from time import sleep

stdout.write('OUT 1\nOUT 2\nOUT 3\n')
sleep(2)
stderr.write('err 1\nerr 2\n')
exit(int(argv[1]))
```

A script demonstrating how to use `Popen`. The arguments to this script will be the external command that we want to execute.

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# A function that takes some subprocess command arguments (list, tuple,
# or string), runs that command, and returns a dict containing STDOUT,
# STDERR, PID, and exit code. Error handling is left to the caller.
def run_subprocess(cmd_args, shell = False):
    p = Popen(cmd_args, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, shell = shell)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    return dict(
        stdout = stdout.decode('utf-8').split('\n'),
        stderr = stderr.decode('utf-8').split('\n'),
        pid = p.pid,
        exit_code = p.returncode,
    )

# Run a command.    
cmd = sys.argv[1:]
d = run_subprocess(cmd)

# Inspect the returned dict.
for k, v in d.items():
    print('\n#', k)
    print(v)
```

If the first script is called `other_program.py` and this script is called `demo.py`, you would run the whole thing along these lines:

```
python demo.py python other_program.py 0  # Exit with success.
python demo.py python other_program.py 1  # Exit with failure.
python demo.py python other_program.py X  # Exit with a Python error.
```

Usage example with `git clone` as discussed with OP in comments:

```
$ python demo.py git clone --progress --verbose https://github.com/hindman/jump

# stdout
['']

# stderr
["Cloning into 'jump'...", 'POST git-upload-pack (165 bytes)', 'remote: Enumerating objects: 70, done.        ', 'remote: Total 70 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 70        ', '']

# pid
7094

# exit_code
0
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate passing a `git clone github.com/user/publicrepo.git` command through your proposed solution?  With a different specified working directory for `Popen`?  This is what the OP asked, and we are encountering errors trying to morph your suggested code into the `git clone` solution for which the OP asks.

Comment: @CodeMed There's not much to demonstrate. I just ran the two scripts in my answer like this: `python demo.py git clone https://github.com/hindman/jump`. Worked fine. And the `run_subprocess()` function is general purpose. As an experiment, I added a `cwd` parameter to the function signature and to the `Popen` call -- also worked fine on my machine. I'm on MacOS in case that matters. If you are on Windows, there might be some differences in the `subprocess` documentation you need to deal with. Good luck!

Comment: We are able to get the first line `cloning into target-folder-name` as `stderr` output, but we are not able to see any of the subsequent lines of output in the console, even though the git repo seems to download.

Comment: We get the same problem when we change your `.splitlines()` into `.split(\n)`

Comment: @CodeMed The problem is related to Git, not Python. When `git clone` is attached to a terminal, I think you'll see the additional progress output you are expecting. See `git help clone` for some discussion of this. But when we run it via `subprocess`, you have to be more explicit with your Git command: for example, `python demo.py git clone --progress --verbose https://github.com/hindman/jump`

Comment: Do you see that your code is still producing an un-iterated bundle of lines for `stderr` as your `v` variable, which is the exact same problem that existed when the OP was posted yesterday?  The OP asks how to iterate the lines of `git clone` output in Python so that the program can determine that the repo was successfully cloned before proceeding.  Try `print("v is: ", v)` to elucidate this problem in your code on your machine.

Comment: @CodeMed No, I don't see that problem. See my newly edited answer, where I added `.split('\n')` and a full `git clone` example.